# Store apps download stuck for ever

Tags: 8.1, lumia-925

Sometimes I get a push notification from the Store;

it says more or less *"12 apps need your intervention"*

Tapping on this message, lead me to the (download screen) list of these 12 apps that needs to be updated.

But the download never starts, never ever...

How to force the download or I might have those apps having an old version.

My phone is a Lumia 925 with 8.1

Thanks

Comment: Try tapping on the apps and selecting "try again."

Comment: @Shawn, I tried but it says "Impossible to connect to the Store now. Try later"

Comment: I assume you're on Wi-Fi?

Comment: Is the time and date on your phone correct?

Comment: yes, time and date are correct